# Rails Webrick monitoring functionality in apache2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ubuntu

Hi I'm wodering if it is possible to get the same webrick monitoring functionality in apache2. Doing a quick reseach on this site an goolge, I found that I can use tail -f to monitor the log realtime. But the info I need is not displayed on the access.log.

On Webrick I can see the complete request that came to the server, this includes all POST parameters that are sent to it. I'm developing a Phonegap aplication that is aiming to a production server with apache, and I need to doublecheck my REST request to the server (exactly as I did in my development environment in Rails with Webrick). That's why tail -f don't fit my needs.

Does anyone has a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution. And it's a stupid answer. I was looking to the apache2 other_vhosts_access.log file, and the info I was getting was:

```
migtrace.com:80 89.131.219.51 - - [16/Sep/2013:12:14:14 +0200] "POST /api/reports.json HTTP/1.1" 200 964 "-" "curl/7.29.0"
```

But if I `tail -f` the rails production.log what I get is:

```
Started POST "/api/reports.json" for 89.131.219.51 at 2013-09-16 12:14:14 +0200
Processing by Api::ReportsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"report"=>{"geo"=>["41.2058334", "1.697777"], "patient_id"=>"X", "patient_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXX", "lunch"=>"{\"pasta\",\"cheese\",\"chocolate\"}", "sex"=>"true"}}
Completed 200 OK in 522ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 259.3ms)
```

That is exactly what I need.